# USB key not readable by a certain device when formatted using fdisk

Tags: fdisk

My mother has a radio that can play MP3s on a USB key. I noticed something strange. When I format it with diskpart from Windows 8.1 my mother's radio has no problems playing the MP3s on a USB key, but if I do the same with fdisk, the radio just says that there are no files on the USB key.

So, this is what I did to make sure, I was not just imagining things:

1. First, I did a quick delete of all the files in the USB key with:

   `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M count=1`

   Well, that deletes the MBR, partition table thoroughly. (I know I do not need to delete 4M to delete everything, but I was not sure about gpt and stuff.)
2. I formatted the USB key with Windows diskpart

   ```
   diskpart
   list disk
   select disk 1
   clean
   create partition primary
   select partition 1
   active
   format fs=fat32 quick
   exit
   ```

   It works perfectly on my mother's radio!
3. Now I format it with fdisk after deleting everything like above with `dd`:

   ```
   sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
   n
   p
   (return 3x)
   a
   w
   sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb1
   ```

   Now for some reason it doesn't work!

Here is the information gparted gives me when I format the USB key with fdisk: [image: device information] [image]

And here is the information when formatted with diskpart:

[image] [image]

Please tell me if there is a way to make the USB key work on my mother's radio without having to boot up Windows all the time. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using gparted live-cd or Linux machine?

Comment: @GAD3R: I installed gparted in lubuntu 15.10. I am using the LXDE desktop, not lubuntu. My question was already answered, though, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the partition type in `fdisk`. Most modern operating systems (including Linux itself) ignore it anyway and just look at the file system. But certain embedded devices don't recognize the file system if the partition type isn't set properly.

While partitioning your USB device, type `t`in `fdisk` and set the partition type to `c` (W95 FAT32 LBA).

Comment: Hey, you were right!! It was not even necessary to set the bootable flag to make it work!

Comment: One thing, though, that is still troubling me. When partitioning with diskpart it worked without the lba flag, but when I set the type to c, there is an lba flag in gparted. Do you know why?

Comment: It still works after removing the lba flag in gparted, though, so, well, nevermind.

Comment: I don't think it really matters. If you don't want it, set the partition type to `b` which is WIN95 FAT32 without LBA (which is probably what Windows did).

Comment: Oh, right, there was that option, too! Thanks!